# strange 3d rendering in firefox on mac

Tags: macos, firefox, webgl, three.js

Today I have encountered a strange problem with firefox, and unlike other problems this a very big one. Without further ado, the screenshots:

What we see in chrome and any other browser (except IE of course), and exactly what we would expect:

[image: Animation start] 
[image: Middle of the animation]

And now to show you my haunted firefox, seems that mac got to it:

[image: This is at the beginning of the animation]
And wait, there is even more!:

[image]

If we analyze a bit how firefox is wrong we can see elements of my desktop icons, desktop wallpaper, it is even rendering my inactive firebug console, etc.
Even if I just feel the need to share this I am very curious why, and how I can solve this "little" problem.
Thank you for your consideration.

With respect,
Blind

Comment: Is there anywhere we can see this to test it?

Comment: unfortunately no, we are working on it on a local server, and due to the nature of how it was done it will require an amount of time to be modified for a fiddle, time we do not have right now, sorry

Comment: Oh well, if you don't have time for creating a isolated test I don't think we can help you. I love the glitches though!

Comment: @mrdoob Indeed it is an interesting effect, I hoped that we could guess where should I head further to investigate. Also I doubt it can be reproduced, it seems that only my imac is affected by this nonsense.

Answer (score 1):

I can't say what the actual cause of your problem is, whether it's your bug or Firefox's bug, but just in case it's helpful, I'll say that the patterns you are seeing remind me of the kind of shader output I got once on my MacBook Pro (“Late 2011”) when I *forgot to write to `gl_FragColor` in my fragment shader*. I could still sort of faintly see the geometry, but everything was filled with the sort of curly pattern you have in your second screenshot (presumably something to do with memory layout in the GPU) and varied in strange ways with the camera direction.

So perhaps

- you did in fact forget to write `gl_FragColor` but Chrome's interpretation happens to work
- Firefox is incorrectly compiling your shader
- your GPU is incorrectly executing Firefox's compilation of your shader but not Chrome's
- you are using a different, broken shader on Firefox due to your conditional on the presence of some extension
- ...